# TSQL Massive Join with multi rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

Is there a easy way to join like this? Table A and B have huge number of rows.

Table A

```
Column 1    Column 2    
1           AA  
2           BB  
3           CC
```

Table B

```
Column 3        
XXX     
YYY     
ZZZ
```

Result

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
1           AA          XXX
1           AA          YYY
1           AA          ZZZ
2           BB          XXX
2           BB          YYY
2           BB          ZZZ
3           CC          XXX
3           CC          YYY
3           CC          ZZZ
```

Comment: Both tables are huge and you want the cartesian product of them?  Is this true?

Comment: Define *huge number of rows* - 1000? 10'000? 100'000? A million? More?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM TableA
CROSS JOIN TableB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select column1, column2, column3
from tablea
outer apply tableb
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74dd5/5)